# Node.js commander issues

Tags: node.js, node-commander

I'm working on adjusting some .js scripts so they can be used with input arguments, rather than adjusting variables in the scripts themselves. I've landed on the commander package, but even following the instructions seems troublesome...

What I want the scripts to be able to do:

- Take some input arguments that are required for the script to run
- Take some additional optional arguments that will adjust what the output looks like

I'm pretty sure I have to do this by combining both the `.argument()` and `.option()` functions.

However, just copy-pasting an example from the commander Github (https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/examples/argument.js) already throws an error:

```
test.js:19
  .argument('<server>', 'connect to the specified server')
   ^

TypeError: program.name(...).argument is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Matthijs.Kramer\MG-DTN\roadmaster-supporting-scripts\test.js:19:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I've tried searching for the specific error, but I can't find anything that'll actually help me... I would be very happy if someone could point out to me what I'm doing wrong, if I can't even get a copy-pasted example working...

Comment: The argument method got added in Commander v8.0.0. What version of Commander do you have installed?

Comment: I think I got it figured out. The package-lock.json in the project I'm working on had a reference to commander 2.20. I got a version 9.4.0 installed and now it works properly.